# Implicit ownership qualifier for parameters/return type is always __strong?

Tags: objective-c, parameters, automatic-ref-counting, return-type, ownership

Since in projects with *automatic reference counting* `NSString * aString;` means implicitly `NSString * __strong aString;`. Does it also count for the **parameters** and return types?

Is

```
- (NSString *)doubleString:(NSString *)aString {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", aString, aString];
}
```

the same compiled code as

```
- (NSString * __strong)doubleString:(NSString * __strong)aString {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", aString, aString];
}
```

and in every similar method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Short answer:* Yes. Both variants produce the same compiled code, as can be verified
by "Product -> Perform Action... -> Assemble ..." from the Xcode menu.

*Longer answer*: (The following references and citations are from the [Clang/ARC](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) documentation.)

**Your question about the return value**. According to
["4 Ownership qualification"](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ownership-qualification),
qualifiers like `__strong` and `__weak` apply to *locations in memory* where a pointer
to an object is stored, and they specify the semantics when loading from or storing to
an *lvalue* ([4.2 Semantics](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#semantics)).

The return value of a method is not such a location in memory (it is not an *lvalue*),
therefore the concept of ownership qualification does not apply here.

It makes not differences if the method is declared as returning `(NSString * __weak)` or `(NSString * __strong)`, there is no difference in the compiled code.

A slightly different question is whether the caller *owns* the 
returned object (it has a +1 retain count) or not. This depends by default on the method name, as explained in ["3.2.2 Retained return values"](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#retained-return-values)
 and ["3.2.3 Unretained return values"](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#unretained-return-values).

**Your question about the parameters.** Declaring the parameter as
`(NSString * __strong)` is identical to `(NSString *)`. This can already be seen
from the Xcode autocompletion (where the "__strong" qualifier is not shown), but
also from the generated Assembly code.

This does not mean that arguments are *retained* when calling a method.
By default, they are not, as explained in
["3.2 Retainable object pointers as operands and arguments"](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#retainable-object-pointers-as-operands-and-arguments).

If an parameter is declared as `__weak`, it *seems* (from the Assembly code) that a temporary weak reference is created in the method, i.e.

```
- (NSString *) doubleString:(NSString * __weak)aString {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", aString, aString];
}
```

is essentially the same as

```
- (NSString *) doubleString:(NSString *)aString {
    NSString *__weak wString = aString;
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", wString, wString];
}
```

But I was not able to find a definite reference for this.

Comment: So it is simply wrong to write __strong/__weak in parameters and return types, and creates bad code as with the __weak parameter or will be ignored as with the return types? (The ownership is declared in other ways).

Comment: @ViktorLexington: If I understand it correctly, __strong/__weak does not make any sense for the *return type*. It looks wrong to me, but seems to be just ignored by the compiler. - Adding __weak to a *parameter* is not wrong, but I do not see *why* it should be done.

Comment: A special case: in parameter lists only, `SomeObjectType**` is implicitly `SomeObjectType * __autoreleasing *` (i.e. a pointer to an autoreleasing pointer). This is done to make `NSError**` work with the pre-existing NSError convention.